# RubyGems Dependency Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

My ruby version is => `ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [i686-linux]`
and I'm using Ubuntu 10.10. I installed every stuff following [this](http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/) blogpost. It was working fine on bash but when I installed ***zsh*** shell and ***oh-my-zsh*** then it started raising following dependency error:

```
/home/manish/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find rails (>= 0) amongst [minitest-1.6.0, rake-0.8.7, rdoc-2.5.8] (Gem::LoadError)
from /home/manish/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
from /home/manish/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1210:in `gem'
from /home/manish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/rails:18:in `<main>'
```

Please tell me if there is any way to fix this.

P.S. => I have installed bundler gem. I also tried to uninstall rvm and reinstall but didn't worked.

Comment: We're going to need a bit more info. Perhaps the output of `rvm info` and `gem list --local`.

Comment: [gem list --local](https://gist.github.com/1245369)

Comment: [rvm info](https://gist.github.com/1245363)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh crap this sucks. I already had rvm script

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

in my ~/.zshrc

but it use to say following error in my zsh shell every time:

```
cd:cd:10: string not in pwd: ..
```

then i rewrote the same script again following the previous one i.e. running same script twice in ~/.zshrc, it ***WORKED***. I still could not figure it out why it raises `string not in pwd....` error on first script and runs the second one.

But yay! feels good to finally use zsh on my Ubuntu also :)

Answer (score 2):

From looking at your `rvm info` it seems that this isn't quite right:

```
  homes:
    gem:          "not set"
    ruby:         "not set"
```

I would have another crack at reinstalling rvm, it shouldn't be that difficult. If you're having problems then you can ask on the channel `#rvm` on the freenode IRC network.

Other things to try would be `rvm reload` followed by `rvm 1.9.2`.

Comment: Have you had another try at reinstalling? Perhaps go for the 'hard' approach and nuke you `~/.rvm` folder.

Comment: yeah I have already done that going through "hard" approach as you mentioned, but it didn't worked out that way either.